# OSX Yosemite cannot delete item from Launchpad and item stuck installing multiple times

Tags: macos, installation, uninstall, launchpad

I've recently upgraded to the developer version of OSX Yosemite, and have upgraded two applications I use. The first is Memory Clean, and the second is Battery Health. Both of these are by "FIPLAB". OK, so I clicked Update next to both items in the App Store (memory clean was first) and after being asked for my password for the app store, proceeded to update memory clean. After this, an error appeared saying Battery Health hadn't installed - not sure of the exact message, but words to that effect.

After this, I have tried installing via the app store, which just seems to install to a point and hang. The second issue is I have a Battery Health icon in my Launchpad that is just an empty icon with the progress of install showing nothing, along with the two that are hanging at the last point

[image]

This also shows in the dock

[image]

I've tried all the stuff I can to remove these from the system to no avail. These include trying to delete using the X that appears when clicking with the option button down. This does nothing. I've also tried restarting fully, Deleting the files in the application folder, and deleting the files in `/Library/Updates/` as per a supposed solution in another article with a similar issue. Any help with this would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

a. Open Terminal and run this command:

open $TMPDIR/../C

b. Locate and delete the folder called "com.apple.appstore"

c. Now, go to this folder and delete everything:

/Library/Updates/

d. Once done removing all these stuff, restart your Mac and empty the trash. Then run this command using Terminal:

defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock

This should solve your issue. :)